# There are any extensions or techniques that allow edit text like code editing in VSCode, to enhance efficiency in editing text documents?

Tags: command, shortcut, text-editor, code-editor

I want to know if there is an extension, complement o something to write text in text editors as you write in Vscode. For example: you write a sentence "My dog's name is Fluffy" you select the sentence and press SHIFT + 8 and you get (My dog's name is Fluffy) instead to replace the sentence with a "(".
Or if you want to delete an entire line you press CMD + SHIFT K or if you want to move up a line you press OPTION + ARROW-UP, or if you want to edit multiple lines at the same time (SHIFT + Option + CMD) and so on.

I tried to find something like that but I couldn't find it.

I work a lot with code AND text so I miss this options in text editors

Thanks!

I tried to find it searching on Google, asking ChatGPT and people.